# Regex for /abc/def or abc, but not "/Abc", not "//abc", not "abc/def", not "abc/"

Tags: regex

I am creating a regex, but can not find a suitable regex for following case:

1. Only support lower case and "/", "/" must be followed by a lower case letter
2. If slash presents, the first character must be slash
3. Valid: "/abc/def", or "abc", or "/ab/cdefg"
4. Invalid: "/ABC", or "ABC", or "//abc", or "abc/def", or "/abc/"

Comment: Must letters be in groups of 3? If slashes are present, must the first char be a slash? Please clarify. What have you tried? And how didn't it work?

Comment: The letters can be any number in group. If slashes are present, must be the first char. I tried "^[/a-z]+|[a-z]+". how to avoid "//"? how to enable "/" must be followed by a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alternation:

```
^([a-z]+|(/[a-z]+)+)$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/dN5cj4bPCSTgS7).

The regex allows the entire input (via `^(...)$`) to be either:

- `[a-z]+` - all lowercase letters, or
- `(/[a-z]+)+` - a slash then at least 1 lowercase letter, all at least one times

Comment: You are a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want (in Python):

```
import re
strings = ["/abc/def", "abc", "/ABC", "ABC", "//abc", "abc/def", "/abc/"]
for s in strings:
    pat = r'^(([a-z]+)|((/(?=[^/])[a-z]+)+))$'
    print('YES: ' if re.match(pat, s) else 'NO:  ', s)
```

Comment: No, it works, but yours is more succinct.  It doesn't really need to use (?=) since [a-z]+ eliminates that case.

Comment: seems this one treats "abc/" as a valid case. If there is slash, then the first character must be slash. Sorry I didn't mention this at the first place.